# Do these two sentence mean the same? Does the second sentence sound natural to you?

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1. Some children want to challenge themselves by learning a language different from **what** their parents speak at home.
> 2. Some children want to challenge themselves by learning a language different from **the one** their parents speak at home.

Do the above two sentence mean the same thing? 
Does the second sentence sound natural to you? If it is natural, I wonder whether "*different from the one their parents speak at home*" is used to modify "*a language*".

Comment: My vote is for the second sentence. The pronoun *what* in a long sentence might create the confusion of what it applies to. On the other hand, *...the one...* makes it clear that we are talking about **the** language those children's parents speak at home.

Comment: They do mean the same thing.  The first construction is more colloquial.  You'll also find "different **to** the one...", which is usual in Commonwealth English.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct and mean the same thing. In ***different from the one their parents speak at home***, **the one** refers back to **the language**.

Comment: Are you certain the first one is correct?  I am not quite sure, but it seems like it would be more familiar with *what* replaced by *that* or *that which*, and replacing *that* by *what* is a feature of several non-standard dialects (e.g. *This ain't the beer what I ordered*).

Comment: @NateEldredge A native speaker might address your query, but here "what" is perfect.

Comment: I *am* a native speaker and I don't know :-)

Comment: @NateEldredge I am sorry friend. I have no idea :(

Comment: @Man_From_India To my (American) ear, the first sentence sounds natural.  The second sentence is also correct, but using "the one" to refer to another part of the sentence is becoming unusual in American English.  There is a slight difference in meaning between the two sentences.  The first sentence does not say how many languages the parents speak at home.  The second sentence explicitly says the parents speak one language at home.

Comment: @Jasper I agree with you about the difference you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The second question is definitely correct and it sounds perfectly natural. The first question is iffy, but it sounds natural too; it wouldn't raise any eyebrows in normal conversation. I'm not sure that it's completely grammatical, but it's not *glaringly* wrong.

Comment: I think the grammar is fine in the first sentence. "What" is a pronoun used to mean a particular thing, e.g. "different from what the audience expected". I suppose the phrase could also be stated as "different from that which their parents speak", but that seems unnecessarily formal.